# European call option lower bound derivation by Black-Scholes formula

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes, european-options

Derive the lower bound of european call options: $$C(S, t)\geq[S-e^{-r(T-t)}K]^+$$

I know how to derive it using put-call parity, but is there any way to derive from Black-Scholes formula?

Comment: Two questions, is the price of a call option in the BS universe monotonic in volatility and what happens as vol tends to 0?

Comment: You cannot derive a model independent result using a model. I mean, you can do it but it doesn't prove anything beyond the B-S world.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Think of BS formula as a function of $\sigma>0$, $f(\sigma)$, with all other relevant parameters ($S$, $K$, $r$, $t$, $T$) fixed constants. Then show that

1. $f$ is a monotonically increasing function in $\sigma$, by say calculating its derivative wrt to $\sigma$,
2. and calculate $$\lim_{\sigma \rightarrow 0^+} f(\sigma).$$

Note that the main piece of calculation in (2) contains the *'switch'*  $ \ln\frac{S}{{\rm e}^{-r(T-t)}K}$ related to the right hand side of your inequality:

\begin{align}&\lim_{\sigma \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{\ln \left( \frac{S}{{\rm e}^{-r(T-t)}K} \right)\pm\frac{\sigma^2}{2}(T-t)}{\sigma\sqrt{T-t}} 
\\&=\begin{cases} \infty & ,\; \; \; \ln \left( \frac{S}{{\rm e}^{-r(T-t)}K} \right)>0\\ -\infty &, \; \; \; \ln \left( \frac{S}{{\rm e}^{-r(T-t)}K} \right) <0 \\ 0 &, \; \; \;\ln \left( \frac{S}{{\rm e}^{-r(T-t)}K} \right)=0 \\\end{cases}\end{align}